# Can I transfer diagnostic data to Azure storage of different account and with some intermediate API

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

I am building window azure application monitoring utility and for that i have to load test my REST API(on every regions) to get perfmon data through startup task on end user's application and i have asked about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862963/suitable-way-to-scale-rest-api-in-window-azure-to-handle-thousands-of-requests) and got good replies as well and i am doing testing all the ways. Meanwhile in my mind i got some ideas that if i can enable  diagnostic data of end user's azure application and transfer that data to my storage account remotely. is it possible?

If yes then i think it will charge end users aggressively if both are in different regions?!
Can i build some type of intermediate mechanism (REST API with all regions) through which diagnostic data can transfer to my azure storage account so it will not charge to end user any more? and using this way i'll be on right direction to get perfmon data and can remove dependency of startup task.

Please correct me if i understood something wrong with above thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is who owns the storage accounts where diagnostics data is collected by default? When moving data from one storage account to another, there are two costs involved: Transaction Costs and Bandwidth Costs. Transaction cost will always be charged to the owner of the storage account. You can somehow prevent your customer from paying for the bandwidth cost by hosting an application in the same data center as your customer's storage account and then transfer out the data to your storage account by having your application act as a proxy between the source and target storage account.

Yet another idea would be to create a separate storage account under your subscription and have your clients use that to store the diagnostics data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i want to use my storage account directly instead of end user's as you have said in last statement. so in this case transaction cost will reside on my part. and for reduce bandwidth cost can i have some API medium (for all data centers/regions) so the end user can choose one of them  according to their application' region and post diagnostic data to my storage? account

Comment: I don't think you could save on the bandwidth here because the Windows Azure Diagnostics agent is writing the data in the storage account. So your customers will pay for outbound bandwidth as and when diagnostics data is transferred to your storage account. You could possibly create separate storage accounts in each data center and have the applications write locally there. Then periodically you could transfer the data out and aggregate it in one storage account for analysis purpose. That way your clients don't pay for bandwidth or storage transactions.